# Class method to return autoreleased object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, class-method

I have been following the iPhone development videos on iTunes U and so far so good. I think I understood things well enough.

The thing is that on the examples they provide they never create custom class methods just like those that you use on some Foundation classes (like [NSString string]) so I'm not sure as to how I should go about creating my own class method to return an autoreleased instance of my class.

I do know how to create a retained object using an instance method but I'd rather use a class method because I prefer it, I'm just not sure if this implementation would be the most appropriate to return an autoreleased object:

```
+ (PhotoViewController*)initWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
    PhotoViewController *toreturn = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
    toreturn.imageview = imageView;
    [toreturn autorelease];
    return toreturn;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class method can return either a retained or autoreleased object as you wish, and your code returns an autoreleased object perfectly appropriately.

However you should probably name your method differently. Since your method begins with `init`, that implies it is initialising an `alloc`ed object (and should therefore be an instance method rather than a class method). I'd suggest naming the method `photoViewControllerWithImageView:` if it's going to return an autoreleased object.

Also, I'd probably write it as `return [toreturn autorelease];` but I guess that's a style preference of mine.

Comment: I think he's asking whether he's using retain-release right, and you seem to answer every question except this :)

Comment: Class methods shouldn't be prefixed with `init` at all, but Apple's guidelines only cover method names that begin with `alloc` or `new` or contain the word `copy`.

Comment: You're quite right, thank you! I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I like to follow conventions as well (they seem to be important in this field of memory management) so your suggestion concerning the name of the method is important because I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: The standard for returning autoreleased objects from a class constructor should be the form of "clasaNameInitializer". So in your example it should look like +(PhotoViewController*)photoViewControllerWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView;

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good practice to check whether `toreturn` is `nil` or not before accessing `imageview` property.

Comment: Why would that make any difference in this case?

Comment: No it wouldn't. But my experience says it is better to be clear in the code what a return value would be, especially the code will be maintained much later, possibly by someone else. But other may not agree. Sorry I wasn't clear about that in the answer.

Comment: Still not clear what you're getting at here. If the call to `init` fails, the method returns `nil` as it should. What would you do differently?

Comment: To me it's a reminder to co-programmers (or future me) that the return of `init` could be `nil`, for the case where something is added inside this function.  Well... maybe it's totally unnecessary if the project is for Objective-C only. It is like my habit to do so and thank you for giving me a chance to think about it again.

Comment: I understand what you mean about using extra code to make readability easier but can you elaborate on how could init ever fail (if you ran out of memory?)?

Comment: Ok, I understand now (one can implement his one init method).